# Return a subset of String

Tags: javascript

I have this string:

```
'/api/media-objects/e78c7cfa-e469-4edd-8a87-9517a5b9e5da'
```

I want to return only the id ('**e78c7cfa-e469-4edd-8a87-9517a5b9e5da**') after the last '**/**'. The id changes everytime I make an API call. How can I do that using any String functions?

Comment: `'/api/media-objects/e78c7cfa-e469-4edd-8a87-9517a5b9e5da'.split('/').slice(-1)`

Answer (score 0):

You could use `match()` here:

```js
var input = "/api/media-objects/e78c7cfa-e469-4edd-8a87-9517a5b9e5da";
var output = input.match(/[^\/]+$/)[0];
console.log(output);
```

Another regex option would be to do a replacement:

```js
var input = "/api/media-objects/e78c7cfa-e469-4edd-8a87-9517a5b9e5da";
var output = input.replace(/^.*\//, "");
console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `String.prototype.split` which splits a string based on the given separator:

```
const path = '/api/media-objects/e78c7cfa-e469-4edd-8a87-9517a5b9e5da'
const parts = path.split('/')
const id = parts[parts.length - 1] // the last chunk
```

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split

Answer (score 0):

You can create a substring from the position of the last `/` (+ 1 to omit the it) to the end of the string:

```
str.slice(str.lastIndexOf('/') + 1)
```

Note: This assumes that the string will always contain a `/`. If it's possible that it doesn't you have to handle that case.